# sum of independent identical distributed random variables

Tags: probability, independence

I need help to understand sum of independent identical distributed random variables.

> Suppose we have a sequence of i.i.d discrete random variables, $\{X_i:i\geq 1\}$, with common probability mass function $f(k)=1/3$ where $k=1,2,3$. Now, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ for $n\geq 1$.
>   Find the probability that $S_n$ is even and find the probability that $S_n$ is even given that $S_{n-1}$ is even.

When we calculate the probability for $S_n$ is even, I think we are calculating $P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\;\text{ is even})$. At this point, I don't know how to use the property of i.i.d. to find the probability.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding $f(k)$ and how you can check if it is even. Care to elaborate?

Comment: a must be 3 no ?

Comment: @vvnitram yes, it is. fixed

Comment: I also don't understand what $ f(k) $ represents. Can you clarify? What does the probability of $1/3$ represent?

Comment: @MichaelR I don't know, that is the question I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that $S_n=S_{n-1}+X_n$,

$$
P(S_n \text{ even }|S_{n-1} \text{ even})
=P(X_n \text{ even})
=P(X_n =2)=1/3.
$$
Also, 
$$
P(S_n \text{ even }|S_{n-1} \text{ odd})
=P(X_n \text{ odd})
=P(X_n \neq 2)=2/3.
$$
Limiting conditions are
$$
P(S_1 \text{ even })
=P(X_1 \text{ even})
=P(X_1= 2)=1/3
$$
These recursively define all the probabilities using the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):
$$
P(S_n \text{ even})
=
P(S_{n-1} \text{ even})\times P(S_n \text{ even }|S_{n-1} \text{ even}) +
P(S_{n-1} \text{ odd})\times P(S_n \text{ even }|S_{n-1} \text{ odd})
$$
With the more compact notation $p_n=P(S_n \text{ even })$ this translates as
$$
p_n=(1/3)\times p_{n-1}+ (2/3)\times (1-p_{n-1})\qquad p_1=1/3.
$$
You then get
$$
p_1=1/3\quad
p_2=(1/3)(1/3)+(2/3)(2/3)=5/9\quad
p_3=(1/3)(5/9)+(2/3)(1-5/9)=13/27\quad
p_4=(1/3)(13/27)+(2/3)(1-13/27)=41/81, \text{etc}.
$$
With general form (given by Mathematica)
$$
p_n=\frac12\left(1+\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n\right)
$$

Comment: I want to know how do get $p_2=5/9$ without using the formula $p_n$. And, can you explain more about how to do this problem？

Comment: @Simple -- Do the changes help ?

Comment: I still don't know how you get $P(S_n\;\text{is even})=....$

Comment: @Simple : it is the Law of total probability (see link above).

Comment: I see, thanks your help